# Using USB intermet through android phone rename dev name

Tags: linux, debian, udev, android, ppp

I had a issue every time I connect my phone and enable Internet USB, the assosiated interfaces name changes like enx$(random mac).

There's a way to set the name like ppp0 vía udev? I tried vía vendor and productos but it fails.

Comment: Tony did you get the answer?